# Getting NullInjectorError while using inject for guard (since CanActivate is deprecated)

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-router-guards, angular-upgrade

I was using `CanActivate`, but I recently migrated to Angular 16 and since it is deprecated, I tried to use `inject()` as guided by the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#router-class-and-injectiontoken-guards-and-resolvers).

This is how my routing component looks like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ContainerComponent,
    canActivate: [() => inject(MyGuard).canActivate()]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RoutingModuleComponent { }
```

This is how my Guard component looks like:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyGuard {
    canActivate(): boolean {
        return true; // this value is based on a variable
    }
}
```

But now I'm getting this error message while navigating to this:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(M)[At -> At -> At]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for At!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(M)[At -> At -> At]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for At!
    at sp.get (main)
    at Dc.get (main)
    at Dc.get (main)
    at Dc.get (main)
    at ti.get (main)
    at Ur (main)
    at ya (main)
    at Object.Xl (main)
    at Jr.#t.ɵfac [as factory] (7)
```

I also tried to adding this method in the MyGaurd class like this, and used in canActivate of routes:

```
export const AuthGuard: CanActivateFn = (): boolean => {
    return inject(MyGuard).canActivate();
};
```

But it also throws the same error message as above.

1. Updating the route definition to be a function like `canActivate: [() => inject(MyGuard).canActivate()]`
2. Tried Using `CanActivateFn` instead.

Comment: have you tried that like that - `canActivate: [AuthGuard]`

Comment: Yes @SonuSindhu, after creating the `[AuthGuard]` I tried using it in  `canActivate` and it's still throwing the same error.